# Which system or country permits the most flexibility in the real estate market?

Tags: property

As to the idea that a free market is good because it is dynamic and flexible and therefore if citizens altogether feel that something is needed in society, a service of any kind to deal with the changing conditions of the world, then people are less restricted and have the means to organize and innovate and take initiative and create whatever service or mechanism can cater to that common desire or need -

I am curious if this can apply to real estate in some way.

It seems to me like real estate is not a “flexible” sector. For example, when it comes to software, anyone who can access a computer can basically learn how to create software and there are very few kinds of software they could not make. Anyone can contribute and participate at any time. And I think this leads to a culture of innovation.

But real estate seems to me inherently cumbersome or unwieldy. At the bottom, there’s just physical land, undivided into quadrants. But the concept of ownership of land isn’t nimble and elastic. There are very specific rules about what “ownership” of land even means, what lawful rights it even gives you. And there are strict terms about how much land you can or cannot buy, where, and what you can do with it - for example, you can’t just buy a square foot of land anywhere in a city just because you have a use in mind for it. It’s probably not on offer.

So, is there any real estate system in any country that is inherently flexible, such that anything that someone wants, they could more easily find, because there are less restrictions and controls on how land is traded?

Thanks very much

Comment: Hi! This seems to about Law, not the discipline of Economics?

Comment: I think you will have to define what exactly you mean by 'flexible' either way.

Comment: I’m not sure because I don’t know much about property law but one way of attempting to define a dynamic real estate market would be a high degree of people feeling like they can buy what they want. For example in Berlin arguably there’s too much demand, not enough supply, so the economy isn’t optimal here (it seems). An optimal market would perfectly match all demand, whatever kind, with supply.